# How can I pass parameter from Apache CXF to Camel

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I am working currently on project where Apache CXF is integrated with Apache Camel. Apache CXF is a solution that we use to expose a WebService then marshal/unmarshal SOAP request and pass it to Camel. This is pretty standard. By default a POJO dataFormat in ApacheCXF is used however there is a need for getting some information form SOAP headers "" and pass it to Camel. My question is how to do this? When I use Interceptor in Apache CXF I can get information that I need but I cannot pass it then to Camel. The class below is a CXF Interceptor

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    //..... some variables 

     @Override
     public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        //..some logic  and then setting a variable

        message.getExchange().put("Foo", "Bar");
     }
 }
```

... and class below is Camel Processor that is eventually called:

```
public class MyCamelProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //how can I read information from CXF Intercptor here? 
        //how can I read "Foo" value?           
    }
}
```

I understand that Exchange class that is used by Apache CXF is different then Exchange used by Camel however there should be a way of passing information between these two integrated technologies?

Comment: I think you can access the soap headers, where you want to get the information from, in the route. See http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Comment: Hi, I want to do the same. Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I solved it how follow:

In my context, I have a consumer service with camel-cxf component which is routed to Processor.

CxfEndpoint class from Camel has a method call setInInterceptors:

```
public void setInInterceptors(List<org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Interceptor<? extends org.apache.cxf.message.Message>> interceptors)
```

Therefore, if we define the next in our beans definitions file:

```
...
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="consumerId" 
    address="/myservice"
    serviceClass="com.example.service.MyServiceSEI">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="myInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint> 

<bean id="myInterceptor" class="com.example.interceptors.MyInterceptor" />
```

Then, in our custom Interceptor we can set any variable in a map

```
...
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
...

public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
  public MyInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
  }

  @Override
  public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
    //..some logic  and then setting a variable

    message.getExchange().put("Foo", "Bar");
  }
}
```

Finally, we can get the variables in our Processor, using org.apache.cxf.message.Message class, different from org.apache.camel.Message used with Exchange.getIn() method

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.message.CxfConstants;

public class MyCamelProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //how can I read information from CXF Intercptor here? 
        //how can I read "Foo" value?
        Message cxfMessage = exchange.getIn().getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, Message.class); 
        String foo = (String) cxfMessage.getExchange().get("Foo");

        // read message from camel context
        org.apache.camel.Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Getting-entire-Soap-Message-with-header-and-body-in-Payload-mode-td5753162.html